# Vuex state is not mutated by a general function whilst a dedicated function does mutate it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, lokijs

I have a LokiJS-provided storage which I use to update the Vuex state using mutations in the `autoloadCallback`.

LokIJS storage:

```
var db = new loki('mydatabase', {
  autoupdate: true,
  autoload: true,
  autoloadCallback: setupHandler
})
```

Vuex state and mutations:

```
const state = {
  ads: []
}

const mutations = {
  updateArray(from, to) {
      from = to
  },
  updateAds() {
      state.ads = db.getCollection('ads').data
  }
}
```

And the callback itself:

```
function setupHandler() {
  setupCollection('ads') // Just sets up the collection if it doesn't exist
  db.getCollection('ads').insert({dummy: "Dummmy!"})

  mutations.updateArray(state.ads, db.getCollection('ads').data)
  mutations.updateAds()    
}
```

The issue here is that calling the `updateArray(state.ads, content)` **does not** change the `state.ads` to `content`, but the `updateAds()` function which does essentially the same thing, just does not accept arguments and have them hardcoded, does change the `state.ads` accordingly.

What is the underlying problem with my approach to write a general function to updateArray? Is there a way to do it?

---

Here is an [JSFiddle MCVE example](https://jsfiddle.net/sjaustirni/bru0mkto/) of this behaviour.

Comment: You can't directly replace the state like you are trying to do in `updateArray`, where `from` is effectively the `state`. If you want to replace the complete state you need to use the `replaceState` method of the store instance. Moreover, you're not really using Vuex as intended. Mutations are intended to receive the state object and mutations should be *commited* via the store.

Comment: @Bert: I don't want to replace the whole state though. I have many an array in the state (just stripped it down to simplify it for you) and I need to update only the very specific array. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @Bert: I am using it like you have described in the components, however, I need to load the data from the LokiJS database first. Is there an idiomatic way to do it?

Comment: As I show below you can call methods on the store without using `this.$store`, you just need a reference to the store object. So *outside* a component, you would do it it same way you would *inside* the component, it's just a matter of how you get to the store.

Comment: @Bert: I see. It is unfortunate though, because even though the JSFiddle example does have access to the store object, in my application it is a module which I `export default { ... }`. I have no idea how I would get the store object then.

Comment: Typically you export the store object and just import it where you need it.

Comment: Thanks @Bert, it solved my issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the specifics of `loki` I think you need to make the following changes.

Your mutation should look like this:

```
const mutations = {
  updateArray(state, to) {
      state.ads = to
    }
}
```

And your setupHandler function should look like this:

```
function setupHandler() {
  setupCollection('ads')
  db.getCollection('ads').insert({dummy: "Dummmy!"})

  store.commit('updateArray', db.getCollection('ads').data)
}
```

Mutations are functions that accept the state as the first parameter, and an object argument containing parameters as the second. Mutations should be *committed* using the store's `commit` method.

Here is your [fiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/bru0mkto/15/).